# Javascript and CSS Lightbox that can view PDFs

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, lightbox, lightbox2

Has anyone ever found any lightbox type javascript / css code that can display PDFs?  I have tried many libraries and none have worked for me.  The environment needs to be IE6/IE7 compatible.

I am looking for something similar to this:
[Lightbox 2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://stickmanlabs.com/lightwindow/

Specifically, check out the demo "Flash Paper" for embedding PDFs

Comment: +1 for linking to flash paper. That requires that the PDF be converted to flash, however, which runs against the original request. It's an option to be considered, though.

Comment: I know it's not 100% on, but if you want to avoid embedded iframes, relying on Adobe's PDF player, etc, it's a good option. :)

Answer (score 1):

Good luck finding anything that will display a PDF in browser without a plugin.

You might consider embedding an IFrame that points to the PDF in a lightbox style. That's about the best you'll be able to do, though.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: that's.... that's amazing. Javascript. Is there nothing it can't do?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: and here I was going to say "lambda expressions"

Comment: I'm not a CS expert, but I found http://www.paulfree.com/11/javascript-lambda-expressions/ (but JS offers other nice capabilities, but you'll know that already).

Answer (score 1):

To sum up your options:

**If a screen-shot** of a portion of the PDF is good enough, then as tomlog answered, you could find a library or existing code to extract said portion as an image, and display that image in the "lightbox".

If, however, you need *actual PDF-viewing functionality*, it **can not** be done in IE6/7 without loading into an Adobe Flash/swf object, or contained within the official Adobe Reader browser plug-in somehow.

Going the **plug-in** route, you will have to use an **iFrame**.

If the **Flash**/embedding approach seems better, jvenema suggested http://stickmanlabs.com/lightwindow/ which has a "Flash Paper" demo (Flash Paper is the *official* way to embed PDF documents) you could check out, or embedding something else, as seen at http://www.scribd.com/ and others.

Comment: Scribd looks like a great option. Free,embedable PDF viewing w/o flash. It even has an API that provides full document management. 

http://www.scribd.com/developers

Answer (score 1):

[artViper's bumpbox](http://www.artviper.net/bumpbox-demo/)

> **Bumpbox 2.0** a lightbox clone with support for PDF, flv, swf, audio, images, inline HTML and remote html files. Now also  plays
>   Youtube© & Vimeo© videos directly out of the  box!

Answer (score 0):

If it's not here, it's not anywhere: [lightbox clones](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/)

Comment: And, I think you're probably going to need to iframe it in, as Randolpho is 100% correct above.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of solutions here

You could embed the PDF in an iframe (in a lightbox or panel) like http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/iframe-pdf.html

Otherwise you could upload the PDF to a document sharing site like Issuu and embed their swf in your web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a PDF library that allows you to convert each page to an image (JPEG, GIF or something), then you could display those in your lightbox.

Obviously you would lose all the zooming and paging functionality of the PDF.